# How to remove images from Cloudinary by Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, cloudinary

Upload and set default controller functions are working perfectly. However, we are trying to implement delete image from Cloudinary as well. How can it be done?
In the documentation it was confusing. Here is the code:

```
 const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
    const HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

    const User = require('../models/userModels');

    cloudinary.config({
      cloud_name: 'name',
      api_key: 'key',
      api_secret: 'secret'
    });

    module.exports = {
      UploadImage(req, res) {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.image, async result => {
          await User.update(
            {
              _id: req.user._id
            },
            {
              $push: {
                images: {
                  imgId: result.public_id,
                  imgVersion: result.version
                }
              }
            }
          )
            .then(() =>
              res
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .json({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' })
            )
            .catch(err =>
              res
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .json({ message: 'Error uploading image' })
            );
        });
      },

      DeleteImage(req, res) {
    cloudinary.uploader.destroy(req.params.image, async result => {
      await User.update(
        {
          _id: req.user._id
        },
        {
          $pull: {
            images: {
              imgId: result.public_id,
              imgVersion: result.version
            }
          }
        }
      )
        .then(() =>
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .json({ message: 'Image deleted successfully' })
        )
        .catch(err =>
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: 'Error deleting image' })
        );
    });
  },

      async SetDefaultImage(req, res) {
        const { imgId, imgVersion } = req.params;

        await User.update(
          {
            _id: req.user._id
          },
          {
            picId: imgId,
            picVersion: imgVersion
          }
        )
          .then(() =>
            res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ message: 'Default image set' })
          )
          .catch(err =>
            res
              .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
              .json({ message: 'Error occured' })
          );
      }
    };
```

We are using Node.js Express with Mongoose. How can we include extra function here that will remove images?

Answer (score 5):

There are two options to delete an image from cloudinary:

1. By using the admin API. For example in Node:

`cloudinary.v2.api.delete_resources(['image1', 'image2'],
  function(error, result){console.log(result);});`

2. Using our upload API:

`cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy('sample', function(error,result) {
  console.log(result, error) });`

Please note that using our admin API is rate limited and you might want to use the second option.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've edited code in the question. Should it look like that with DeleteImage function?

Comment: No. When I try to remove the image nothing happens and there is no any error.

Comment: Can you print the result: `console.log(res)`?

Answer (score 4):

it just because your req.params.image is like https:https://res.cloudinary.com/your/image/upload/v1663358932/Asset_2_bdxdsl.png

instead write your delete request like so :

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy('Asset_2_bdxdsl', function(error,result) {
   console.log(result, error) })
```

ps: Asset_2_bdxdsl is your image name without prefix .png !!

Answer (score 0):

```
const cloudinaryDeleteImg = async (fileToDelete) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        cloudinary.uploader.destroy(fileToDelete, (error, result) => {
            console.log('result :: ', result);
            resolve({
                url: result.secure_url,
                asset_id: result.asset_id,
                public_id: result.public_id,
            }, {
                resource_type: "auto",
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.